# Greatest Common Divisor Summation Simplification

Tags: number-theory

Does anyone know how to simplify the following formula:

$\sum_{a=0}^b\text{GCD}(a,b)\chi(\frac{ka}{b})$

where $0<k<b$ is an integer, and $\chi(x)=\begin{cases}1 & x\notin\mathbb{Z}\\ 0 & x\in\mathbb{Z}\end{cases}$.

Obviously when $k=1$, we have:

$\sum_{a=0}^b\text{GCD}(a,b)\chi(\frac{ka}{b})=\sum_{a=1}^{b-1}\text{GCD}(a,b)$

But by playing with Mathematica, I also managed to find an expression for $k=2$:

$\sum_{a=0}^b\text{GCD}(a,b)\chi(\frac{2a}{b})=2\sum_{a=1}^{\lfloor\frac{b-1}{2}\rfloor-1}\text{GCD}(b-a-1,a+1)$

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Make the "is an integer" condition into $k a = d b$ for an integer $d$ and see where that leads

Answer (score 1):

Your sum could be written

$$\sum_{d|ka}\gcd(a,d)$$

To simplify things, let's start with $k=p$ a prime that does not divide $a$.

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{d|pa}\gcd(a,d)&=\sum_{d|a}\gcd(a,d)+\sum_{d|a}\gcd(a,dp)\\
&=2\sum_{d|a}\gcd(a,d)\\
&=2\sum_{d|a}d\\
&=2\sigma(a)
\end{align}
$$
since $\gcd(a,d)=\gcd(a,dp)$. The function $\sigma$ is the sum of the divisors.

Now, let's take $k$ any integer coprime with $a$:
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{d|ka}\gcd(a,d)&=\sum_{d'|k}\sum_{d|a}\gcd(a,dd')\\
&=d(k)\sum_{d|a}\gcd(a,d)\\
&=d(k)\sigma(a)
\end{align}
$$
where $d(k)$ is the number of divisors of $k$.

The case when $k$ is not coprime with $a$ seems more difficult. If I find something, I'll edit this answer.